# Infinite-dimensional Quadratic Programming Problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, quadratic-programming

In mathematical programming, one popular problem is the quadratic programming problem
\begin{align}
&{\rm maximize}~~~1/2x^TQx+c^Tx \\
& {\rm subject to}~~~Ax\leq b,
\end{align}
where Q and A are real finite-dimensional matrices and x,c, and b are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

My question is about this problem where Q and A are infinite-dimensional linear operators and x,c, and b are vectors in an arbitrary real Hilbert space H. By a simple net surfing I have found some results on necessary and sufficient conditions of this problem but I do not know how to solve it. In other words I do not know is there any algorithm in infinite-dimensional quadratic programming!

I would be grateful if you could help me.

Comment: Hmm, if the problem is truly infinite-dimensional, won't it be difficult to even represent the inputs and outputs of any algorithm?

Comment: Your opinion seems logical. Do you mean there is no way?

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems behind this question:

- How do you define inequalities $x\ge0$ in an infinite-dimensional space?
- It might happen that constraint qualifications are generically not satisfied. For instance, it is not guaranteed that $\{x\ge0 \}$ has non-empty interior.

If you have a specific setting in mind, then you can try to apply traditional finite-dimensional methods: interior point, penalty methods, semi-smooth Newton methods, etc.